# Wordpress Cron Job: Ignore Cron job during the site's inactivity period

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I did Cron job to fetch data from API every minute
But I am facing a problem which is when the site is inactive, a number of tasks that have not been implemented are saved, and when the site becomes active, all of these tasks are executed.

Is there a way for me to ignore all operations during the period of inactivity and request api once and follow up on the continuation of the Cron job

I am referring to accumulated scheduler actions that then all execute at once, when the next visitor comes

```
function my_schedules($schedules){

   if(!isset($schedules["my1min"])){
        $schedules["my1min"] = array(
            'interval' => 60,
            'display' => __('Once every 1 min'));
    }

    return $schedules;
}

add_filter('cron_schedules','my_schedules');

wp_schedule_event(strtotime('01:00:00'), 'my1min', 'callback_scheduled_my');


add_action( 'callback_scheduled_my', 'callback_scheduled_my' );

function callback_scheduled_my(){

   //my code

}
```

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by “inactive”?

Comment: Cron job in WordPress depends on site visits, so when there are no visits, the site is inactive

Comment: You need to call CRON from the server.

Comment: I am developing a plugin for any user to download, so I want to rely on Cron Job who is in WordPress and who depends on site visits, without using cron from server

Comment: What are those “tasks” you are talking about? Are you referring to accumulated scheduler actions that then all execute at once, when the next visitor comes and triggers the cron functionality again? Or is that referring to something coming from that external API? The whole explanation of _what exactly_ you want to prevent here, isn’t very comprehensive here so far.

Comment: yes i am referring to accumulated scheduler actions that then all execute at once, when the next visitor comes